# Why is the AUC equal to 1 despite some predictions being incorrect?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, auc

I trained a binary classifiers with the following true and predicted labels:

```
y_true = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0]
y_pred = [0.468, 0.427, 0.528, 0.268, 0.36, 0.131, 0.38, 0.774]
```

When running the following code, I get an AUC of 1. However, one can see that there are incorrect predictions (for example, the first item has a prediction of 0.46, with a correct label of 1).

Why is the AUC equal to 1 despite some predictions being incorrect?

Code:

```
from sklearn import metrics
fpr, tpr, thresholds = metrics.roc_curve(y_true, y_pred) 
auc = metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
```

Comment: There exists a threshold where all your predictions are accurate (in this case 0.3 looks to be one of those thresholds), meaning all true positives are rated higher than false positives, meaning probability of scoring a positive example higher than a negative one is 1.

Comment: Bonus: Don't use AUC for imbalanced data.